# Removing Outliers from data set KeyError: False in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm trying to remove outliers from my data set using zscore. Just one of my columns, 'Amount' is numeric so I'm wanting to remove the entire row if 'Amount' contains a number classified as an outlier. Here is my code, I call the entire data set 'Data'

'''

```
#Change 'Amount' data to numeric
Data['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(Data['Amount'])

#Calculating and printing zscore
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(Data['Amount']))
print(z)

#Identifying and printing the outliers
threshold = 3
print(np.where(z > 3))

#Removing the outliers
Data = Data[Data['Amount'][(z < 3).all()]]
```

'''

Here is the error coming up:
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: False

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, the error is occurring in the last line of code. Is there a better, easier way to remove outliers

Comment: `Data[(z < 3).all()]`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where your error is specifically, but I can say that the below is more standard practice and was able to do what you were looking for when I tested it.

I say it's more standard practice for two main reasons:

1. You keep the zscores for each record in the same DataFrame, rather than a separate object.
2. When making changes to a DataFrame, especially for conditional deletions like this, it's better practice to use an "inplace" operation, if possible. Doing this as regular practice helps minimize possible errors where the DataFrame isn't changing exactly how you expect it to.

```
Data["z"] = np.abs(stats.zscore(Data["amount"]))
Data.drop(Data.loc[Data["z"]>3].index,inplace=True)
```